# How to draw bifurcation diagram:$\dot{x}=x^3-C*sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$

Tags: bifurcation, chaos-theory

I want to draw the bifurcation diagram but since I can't solve this equation by hand it is difficult. I can graph it by having $f1=x^3$ and $f2 = C*sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$ and the intersection points are the fixed points but I don't know how to use this to draw the bifurcation diagram.

$\dot{x}=x^3-C*sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$

C is a real number. Can someone please show me how to draw it?